# How to inject object into setter that declared final in parent class with using just annotations?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

How to inject object by using just annotations in parent class by using getter/setter method which declared like `public final someSetter()`?

As far I understand if that method would declared just public

I can do like this...

```
@Override
@Autowired
public void setSomeObject(SomeClass someObject) {...}
```

But method declared like final and I cannot override it.

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the parent, you may be out of luck if you can *only* use annotations.

You could create a different setter, annotate it, and call the parent setter, though.

Comment: It was an abstract question. I understand that annotations are more much clear for user instead of xml configurations but in some cases you cannot use just annotation. And that is sad:(

Comment: @infate There are a lot of situations where I much prefer XML config.

Comment: @infate You might be interested in [this blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx) It explains why it is often not a good idea to use annotations in your classes.